# How can I modify the resulting query in Mongoose without affecting the actual document?

Tags: javascript, java, json, mongodb, mongoose

***Status (as of 5/6/2020):*** Solved, see the identified answer below.

I hope all is well despite the global crisis we are experiencing right now. I am currently doing a school web project and need to render a specific feature assigned to me. I am using **Mongoose** with Express, and Handlebars for templating. Please see the attached model schema and explanation below.

**collegeModel** - Collection A

```
var collegeSchema = new Schema({
    shortName: {type: String},  //value that I intend to synchronously query its occurrence with Collection B
    longName: {type: String},
    logo: {type: String},
    contactUs:{
        telNum: {type: String},
        faxNum: {type: String},
        email: {type: String}
    },
    aboutUs: {type: Array},
    visionMission: {type: String},
    coreValues: {type: String},
    goals: {type: String},
    founderBio: {type: String},
    philosophy: {type: String},
    icon: {type: String}
});
```

**professorModel** - Collection B

```
var professorSchema = new Schema({
    profNumber: {type: Int32},
    college: {type: String},    //value to be compared with shortName
    gender: {type: String},
    profName: {type: String},
    profCourse: {type: String}
});
```

**Pseudocode** - Desired logic to be achieved

```
app.get('/testCount', function(req,res) {
    collegeModel.find({}).lean().exec(function(err,collegeRes){
        var collegeObject = [];
        collegeRes.forEach(function(document){
            professorModel.countDocuments({college:document.shortName}, function(err2,professorCount){
                document.count = professorCount;
                collegeObject.push(document);   //doing a console.log(collegeObject) would return empty objects [].
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I know document.count exists since it returns a value everytime I do console.log(document.count) but when it's pushed it becomes []. Hope you can help me achieve my goal. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you put `console.log(document.count)` ? .countDocuments operations are asynchronous, you won't know when the last `document` will be pushed if you don't keep track of the count. I suggest you use `asyc / await` if your environment supports it.

Comment: I add it right after the first `});`

Comment: Like I said, `countDocuments` is asynchronous, you pass a callback to it and it will execute later. When you `console.log` there the callback wouldn't be executed yet.

Try using `async / await` and `Promise` instead

Comment: Hi @TheeSritabtim, thanks for the help! How exactly would I do this? I apologize as I'm just a beginner in js coding and using MongoDb/Mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries resolve asynchronously, you have to find a way to wait for all of them to complete to make sure you have all the data you need.

One way to solve this is using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (Node.js >= 7.6.0)

```js
app.get('/testCount', async function(req, res) { // note the async keyword
  const collegeRes = await collegeModel.find({}).lean().exec() // .exec() returns a Promise, so you can `await` it.
  const resultPromises = collegeRes.map(async college => { // arrow function is equivalent to function in this context
    const professorCount = await professorModel.countDocuments({ college: college.shortName })
    college.count = professorCount
    return college
  })
  const collegeObject = await Promise.all(resultPromises)
  console.log(collegeObject)
})
```

A bit more readable would be using [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) from `bluebird` or you can also use other promise utility library

```js
  const collegeObject = await Promise.map(collegeRes, college => {
    const professorCount = await professorModel.countDocuments({ college: college.shortName })
    college.count = professorCount
    return college
  })
  console.log(collegeObject)
```

Comment: Hi, Thee! Your answer solved my problem and you were able to explain it to me so clearly. Best of luck to you!